# Escaping backslashes in string

Tags: c#, .net, string, escaping

I would like to know what is a good way to escape back slashes in a string without adding unnecessary slashes to it.

I mean, usually if I want to escape a backslash in a string, the simplest way is to use `String.Replace()` like so:

`string s = someString.Replace("\\", "\\\\");`

A similar thing can be done with regular expressions using `Regex.Replace()`.

Now my question is, lets say I have a string that has some of its back slashes escaped like for example: `"C:\some_folder\\some_file.bin"`

Now if I try and replace the backslashes in that by adding another backslash before each occurrence, I will end up with the following string:

`"C:\\some_folder\\\\some_file.bin"`

No clearly, the `\\\\` are unnecessary, so how do I go about ignoring already escaped characters?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko who said anything about `\t`?

Comment: did you try any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, this is what you want to do-

```
   string path = @"C:\some_folder\\some_file.bin";
   string exactPath = string.Join("\\",path.Split(new char[] { '\\' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a RegEx Approach

```
string Result = Regex.Replace("C:\\some_folder\\\\some_file.bin", "[\\\\]+", "\\");
```

in that case you need to escape for RegEx AND for C#. alternatively you can write

```
string Result = Regex.Replace(@"C:\some_folder\\some_file.bin",@"[\\]+",@"\");
```

because `"\\"` equals `@"\"`